# How to store the actual name of a /*url*?

Tags: bash, unix, hadoop, hdfs

I'm converting a script to HDFS (Hadoop) and I have this cmd:

```
    tail -n+$indexedPlus1 $seedsDir/*url* | head -n$it_size > $it_seedsDir/urls
```

With HDFS I need to get the file using -get and this works.

```
bin/hadoop dfs -get $seedsDir/*url* .
```

However I don't know what downloaded file name is, let alone that I wanted to store in $local_seedsDir/*url*.
Can I know?

KISS tells me:

```
bin/hadoop dfs -get $seedsDir/*url* $local_seedsDir/urls
```

i.e. just name the file as urls locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url=`echo bin/hadoop dfs -get urls-input/MR6/*url* .`
```

then tail and head to extract from url the actual file name and store it in $urls

```
rm $urls
```

But otherwise, just KISS